# mac os x terminal php command not found

Tags: macos, php

I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8. In Terminal, when I enter `php -v`, I get below message:

```
Last login: Sun Dec 16 20:22:05 on ttys000
You have mail.
-bash: e: command not found
~ $cd /
/ $php -v
-bash: php: command not found
/ $
```

My `$PATH` is:

> `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr‌​/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/php5-20121126-100332/bin/php`

When I type `which php`, I simply get an empty output.

Comment: It looks like there's more broken on your machine than just php. I also don't know and OS X that will display 'you have mail', I kinda doubt that the output of these commands are really on an OS X machine (are you ssh'ing into a different system?)

Comment: @Evert Cron jobs will send you mail by default and you'll see that message. (One can disable it by setting the email variable thing in their crontab to `""`, I think.)

Comment: Thanks Waleed.   I will keep trying.  Evert, Thanks for your comments. I will keep checking

Comment: Does /usr/bin/php work? Did you change your bash profile? Actually, what did you do before it stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

hm, that sucks. Showed up fine on my 10.7 machine using php -v or "which php".

You can always try "sudo find /usr/ -name php 2>/dev/null" to do a more complete search.

If it somehow got borked, you could use http://www.macports.org to install php

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I will try macports.org and let you know. Thanks again